Edit existing custom blocks in layout builder
I have an issue with layout builder and existing custom blocks.
When I insert existing custom block from custom block library (either create block inline in layout builder, clone it and then try to import cloned block into layout builder) and click on configure (for the block inserted in lb from library) I don't see all fields (to edit) from that block.
Only if I created block inline in layout builder I have the option to configure all fields.
For some reason I cannot see/edit fields from block when it's imported from custom block library.
Any suggestions?



I don't think global blocks can be edited directly in Layout Builder. Not out of the box, anyway.

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3312145
